# Spring Concordion and Sonar won't work : jar conflict?

Tags: java, spring, sonarqube, concordion

I work on a Gwt/Spring project with maven/jenkins/sonar. For my functionnal tests, I use concordion over [gwt-test-utils](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-test-utils/).

Everything works great except while running the sonar analysis.

Here's the exception for each of these tests :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.sc.r.repository.MyRepository com.sc.r.BootstrapData.myRepository; 
   nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set com.sc.r.repository.MyRepository field com.sc.r.BootstrapData.myRepository to $Proxy110
```

It seems like a jar conflict, but without more informations i don't know.

Due to the "exotic" nature of my configuration, i understand that no one could directly help me.

But how would you investigate if you were in my position ? What should i look for or where should i look ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What makes you think it's a dependency conflict? Can't see much from the exception that would describe it as a conflict.

If you definitely know it's a conflict issue try doing :

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

And isolate the replica jars and remove them from the dependencies in maven using the excludes tag.

Comment: why would it work every time, everywhere except when sonar run the tests ? It must be a jar conflict, maybe surefire or junit.. I don't know..